# Is there a way to install Mac OS on an Azure Virtual machine - or any cloud VM for that matter?

Tags: macos, mac, virtual-machine, cloud, azure

I want to create a virtual development machine on the could for iOS development. I understand it is against Mac OS License agreement to install it on non-Apple hardware. But is there a LEGAL solution to have such VM on any cloud provider?

I also know about [MacinCloud](https://www.macincloud.com/) but I'm looking for a cheaper solution.

Comment: Didn't you answer your own question?  You know its against their license agreement, and non-Apple specific clouds are not going to be running Apple hardware.  Now technically you might be able to do it, but it would be breaking the terms of the license agreement.

Comment: I understand. But as far as the cloud hardware goes, I don't see what type the provider is using. I'm looking for a provider that offers Apple hardware...

Comment: [This StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7308039/94928) has some suggestions, including GoDaddy.  As for this question it is off-topic for SuperUser.

Comment: @FrankGoortani - The only provider that could exist would be Apple.  Apple does not offer cloud computing solutions thus OS X cloud virtual machines cannot exist.

Comment: See https://feedback.azure.com/forums/216843-virtual-machines/suggestions/13826655-mac-os-x-virtual-machines

Comment: Azure DevOps hosted does have Mac OS build agents if you're interested in building software. I haven't tried this so not sure how well it will work for you. (I'm using Azure Devops for other reasons and noticed the MacOS build agent options)  Presumably Microsoft have some Mac hardware somewhere. They must have to test Office 365. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml Shame whoever closed this question didn't really say where it should be posted instead

Comment: See: https://wp.sjkp.dk/running-macos-using-virtual-box-in-azure/ for how to do this. I suggest practice building a Hackintosh locally to make it sure it should work. Then try this article.

Comment: See AWS EC2 Mac Instances: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-use-mac-instances-to-build-test-macos-ios-ipados-tvos-and-watchos-apps/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> But is there a LEGAL solution to have such VM on any cloud provider?

There are no legal solutions to run a OS X VM on **ANY** cloud provider. Microsoft's, Amazon's, and Google's cloud computing solutions do not use Apple hardware.

Somebody would need to use Apple hardware as their backend server in order to provide virtual machines for cloud computing.  The example you used is not cloud computing, they rent you physical hardware, thats the reason they are expensive.

Comment: I know this answer is 7 years old now but I thought I would add this comment in case anyone like me stumbles across this post. It is now possible using [Amazon EC2 Mac Instances](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/mac/).